# How to check for read access on files using C#

Tags: c#, windows, security

Given a file, I need to list all the users that have read access to that file using C# and .NET framework 4. Not interested in adding or listing any other permissions.
Assume the directory is a local directory and local users are enough.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: Is this all users on an entire domain, or just local users, or anyone who has access, on the local filesystem, a share, a webserver, FTP, or what?

Comment: Just edited the question. Local directory and Local users. Just what you get when you right click on a file and check the security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to get that list, but here's an idea. You can loop through the access control rules and check which users can read the file. Beware that some rules **allow** access while others **deny** it. Here's a starting point:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

...

FileSecurity security = File.GetAccessControl(@"C:\MyFolder\My File.txt");

AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = security.GetAccessRules(
   true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ace in acl)
{
   var user = ace.IdentityReference.Value;
   var rights = ace.FileSystemRights;
   var allowOrDeny = ace.AccessControlType;
   // ...
}
```

Check [FileSystemAccessRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.aspx) for further information.

Comment: Yeap, the thing is I've seen a lot of examples on how to add/remove permissions, but I can't find one about retrieving them.

Comment: @martincho the example I posted is about retrieving them. I don't know if there's a more direct way of doing it, but processing the ACL list sounds doable.